# Internet & Ping Working but can't connect via SSH

Tags: centos, ssh, firewall

I am having CentOS 6 on my server.

When I disable the firewall via the following commands, ssh starts working fine, however when I turn the firewall back on, ssh stops.

```
service iptables save  
service iptables stop  
chkconfig iptables off
```

Here is the list of iptable rules

```
[root@server1 ~]# sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N IPTABLES-UP
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 58.74.16.32/28 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 121.97.80.16/28 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 203.177.90.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 122.55.79.144/28 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 125.212.38.80/28 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.50.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.60.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.70.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.160.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.170.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.150.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.237.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.235.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.228.0/22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 26 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 26 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
```

The port of SSH is also not changed.

Can you help me out why I am not able to connect via ssh?

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: I am connected via Serial Console, I can't copy the text :(

Comment: I have transcribed the contents of your screenshot for you, but you may want to check for errors in transcription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I read on your screenshot you have several iptables rules and the last one drop all the rest

```
iptables -A input -j DROP
```

Before droping the rest of the request you should add a rule to allow ssh into your server

```
iptables -A input -p 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Expanding on this answer with more explanation, rather than just a command, would improve it.